# Next.js - Metatags not prerendered when using redux-persist

Tags: docker, next.js, seo

I have a problem with facebook crawler, they only show something like the text below in the thumbnail:

[image: facebook thumbnail]

I have an example of a one of my pages: (This is just a test and does not contain open graph tags but even if they are there the fb thumbnail is not working)

```
import Head from "next/head";
const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Hello</title>
      </Head>
      <p>Hellow</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

The expected thing is to inspect the source and be able to view this:

```
<head><title>Hello</title><head>
```

But instead we I am getting this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style data-next-hide-fouc="true">body{display:none}</style><noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true"><style>body{display:block}</style></noscript><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><meta name="next-head-count" content="2"/><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1660199366445"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660199366445" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1660199366445" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660199366445" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/test.js?ts=1660199366445" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1660199366445" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1660199366445" defer=""></script><noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript></head><body><div id="__next"></div><script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1660199366445"></script><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{}},"page":"/test","query":{},"buildId":"development","nextExport":true,"autoExport":true,"isFallback":false,"scriptLoader":[]}</script></body></html>
```

I can view the title once I visit domain.com/test but that's because javascript is filling the title after loading but the problem is that Its supposed to render the title in the beginning.

The problem is here:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";

import AppLayout from "../components/layout/AppLayout";
// import { wrapper } from "../store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistor, store } from "../store";
import { injectStore } from "../api";

injectStore(store);

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use layout that is defined in page, otherwise use the app's layout.
  const getLayout =
    Component.getLayout ||
    function getLayout(page) {
      return <AppLayout>{page}</AppLayout>; // App Layout
    };
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

// export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
export default MyApp;
```

After I change my code to look like below and it pre-renders the
meta tags and facebook's crawler can view the tags but that involves removing my Redux Provider (which is needed), any ideas?

**NOTE: The problem is with redux-persist and PersistGate. I noticed it after testing with a new project and redux (without persisting the state). SEO works normally if working with redux alone.**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";

import AppLayout from "../components/layout/AppLayout";
// import { wrapper } from "../store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistor, store } from "../store";
import { injectStore } from "../api";

injectStore(store);

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use layout that is defined in page, otherwise use the app's layout.
  const getLayout =
    Component.getLayout ||
    function getLayout(page) {
      return <AppLayout>{page}</AppLayout>; // App Layout
    };
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

// export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Have you tried defining the meta tags in a `pages/_document` file? Doing this will help you know if this is persistent across all pages or specific to the one you're having issues with. For reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Comment: Thanks for your comment but now I know the issue has to do with Redux's Prover

Answer (score 0):

**Potential solution:**

So basically the  is causing the problem of not pre-rendering the meta tags so one option is to add your provider to every page and not wrap your meta-tags inside of the provider but if you have a lot of pages that's not an option so maybe just adding it to the ones that need the provider's data. (of course that is not an option if you are not persisting the state because you would lose your state)

**The solution specific to my project**

I have different layouts, the only place where I require the store's state is in the admin's dashboard.

So I have a layout for that and in my layout I added the provider because SEO is not important for the dashboard because that has to be seen by few people only.

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistor, store } from "../../store";

import { injectStore } from "../../api";
import DashboardLoginCheck from "./DashboardLoginCheck";
injectStore(store);

const DashboardLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <DashboardLoginCheck />
          <div className="dashboard">
              {children}
          </div>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default DashboardLayout;
```

And my code in _app.js is:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";

import AppLayout from "../components/layout/AppLayout";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const getLayout =
    Component.getLayout ||
    function getLayout(page) {
      return <AppLayout>{page}</AppLayout>; // App Layout
    };
  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
}

export default MyApp;
```

I know there could be a better solution but this could still help anyone, I hope someone else can help us all with a better solution.